# php search one dimensional array value and if value not present in mutidimentional array add element with zero value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array one is list of hours array and second is my result array. I have to fill `$current_play` array with 24 hours elements.

For that first I search hours array value into second array with `$watch_hour` value. If value not match not value fill with zero value and add array elements with zero value.

first array:

```
$hoursArray=

['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23'];
```

Second Array:

```
$result = array(
    array(
        "code" => "BA",
        "name" => "BARCA",
        "current_play" => array(
            array(
                "whours" => "20",
                "value" => "6"
            ),
            array(
                "whours" => "5",
                "value" => "6"
            ),
            array(
                "whours" => "6",
                "value" => "6"
            ),
            array(
                "whours" => "8",
                "value" => "6"
            ),
            array(
                "whours" => "9",
                "value" => "6"
            )
       )
   )
);
```

I am trying below code but its not working;

```
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $hoursArray ); $i ++) {
    foreach ($result as $t){
        if($t['watch_hour'] == $hoursArray[$i]){
            $result[$v['code']]['cplay'][] = array('whours'=> $hoursArray[$i],'value' => $v['value']);
        } else{
            $result[$v['code']]['cplay'][] = array('whours'=> $hoursArray[$i],'value' => "0");
        }
    }
}
```

required array will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [code] => BA
        [name] => BARCA
        [current_play] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [whour] => 0
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [whour] => 1
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [whour] => 2
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [whour] => 3
                    [value] => 0
                )
            [4] => Array
            (
                    [whour] => 4
                    [value] => 6
            )
            [5] => Array
            (
                    [whour] => 5
                    [value] => 6
            )
            [6] => Array
            (
                    [whour] => 6
                    [value] => 6
            )
            and so on for each hours element....
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: what is $v variable ???

Comment: this is my main array variable.Before this array I have one  
  array,          foreach($geogrphyViewershipdata as $v) {
   $result[$v['code']]['code']        = $v['code'];
   $result[$v['code']]['name']        = $v['name'];  
                       $result[$v['code']]['current_play'][] =array('watch_hour'=> $v['watch_hour'],'value' => $v['value']);  After pring this array I get result array.

Comment: @BhagwanPawar  i think you want this:- https://eval.in/972997

Comment: so edit your question and make it more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've tried to solve it is to extract the hours played out into an indexed array using `array_column()`.  Then for each hour check if there is a value and add it in if not found.  Then take the result of this and put it back into the main array (sorted)...

```
$currentPlay = array_column($result[0]['current_play'], null, "watch_hour" );
foreach ( $hoursArray as $hour )    {
    if ( isset($currentPlay[$hour]) === false )  {
        $currentPlay[$hour] = array(
                "watch_hour" => "$hour",
                "value" => "0"
        );
    }
}
sort($currentPlay);
$result[0]['current_play'] = $currentPlay;
print_r($result);
```

The output is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => CA
            [name] => Canada
            [current_play] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 0
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 1
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 2
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 3
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 4
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 5
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 6
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 7
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 8
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 9
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 10
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 11
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 12
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 13
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 14
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 15
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 16
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 17
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 18
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 19
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 20
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 21
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 22
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [watch_hour] => 23
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Update:**
To do this for each country...

```
foreach ( $result as $key => $country ) {
    // $currentPlay = array_column($country['current_play'], null, "watch_hour" );
    $currentPlay = array();
    foreach ( $country['current_play'] as $item )   {
        $currentPlay[$item["watch_hour"]] = $item;
    }
    foreach ( $hoursArray as $hour )    {
        if ( isset($currentPlay[$hour]) === false )  {
            $currentPlay[$hour] = array(
                "watch_hour" => "$hour",
                "value" => "0"
            );
        }
    }
    sort($currentPlay);
    $result[$key]['current_play'] = $currentPlay;
}
```

Comment: I have to print value also those watch_hours value match with hours array.In main array watch_hour index six having value is 6

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: We are near to the result but I have multiple current_play fro different country also so $result[0]['current_play'] is working for single array we have to do by foreach loop?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was at the gym.  The updated code should process it for each country.

Comment: I have one issue Nigael array_column is not support bcz I am using lower version for development.what is diiffrent wa.

Comment: I've changed the update to do `array_column()` in a `foreach` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$currebt_hours = array_column($result[0]['current_play'], 'watch_hour');
$arrdiff = array_diff($hoursArray, $currebt_hours);
foreach ($arrdiff as $value) {
  $entry = array();
  $entry[watch_hour]=$value;
  $entry[value]=0;
  $result[0][current_play][]=$entry;
}
```